# How do you execute map reduce operations with the Reactor framework?

Tags: java, reactor

Can someone please show a code example of how to perform map/reduce operations via the [Reactor](https://github.com/reactor/reactor) framework?

Let's say I have a `Collection<Map>`.  I want to:

1. Transform each `Map` instance to an object of type `Foo` concurrently (each instance is totally independent of another - there is no need to convert each serially/iteratively).
2. When all of them are converted, I want a a method, `onReduce(Collection<Foo> foos)`, to be called - the argument contains all of the resulting `Foo` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you don't need `reduce` at all. The `collect` and `consume` are for you:

```
@Test
public void testCollect() {
    Stream<String> stream = Streams.defer(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")).get();
    stream.map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect()
            .consume(integers -> assertThat(integers, Matchers.contains(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
}
```

This sample (Java 8) demonstrates how to send a `List<String>` to Reactor's `Stream`, convert each `item` to `String`, `collect` them to the `List<Integer>` and do `process` on the result `List`.

**UPDATE**

Note `collect(5)` isn't needed: `Stream` applies `batchSize` from deffered `Collection`.
Looks like `.collect(int batchSize)` has been introduced recently.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot - I wasn't aware of the `collect` semantics.

Comment: Just trying to be helpful: some code examples on the [wiki page](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/wiki/Streams) would be much appreciated and would have eliminated my need to ask this question.

Comment: I'm confused: you show the `collect` method as taking an argument (`5`), but the [Stream API](http://reactor.github.io/docs/api/reactor/core/composable/Stream.html) does not show `collect` as accepting arguments.  Thoughts/

Comment: Updated an answer. Re. samples: feel free to raise an issue: https://github.com/reactor/reactor/issues?state=open

Comment: In 1.1.0.M3 it is already here: https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/v1.1.0.M3/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/composable/Stream.java#L451

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! Great stuff.