# How to perform multi-threaded map/reduce using Reactor framework 2.x?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, mapreduce, reactor

I previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844717/how-do-you-execute-map-reduce-operations-with-the-reactor-framework) for Reactor 1.x:

> Let's say I have a `Collection<Map>`. I want to:
>
> Transform each `Map` instance to an object of type `Foo` concurrently (each instance is totally independent of another - there is no need to convert each serially/iteratively).
>
> When all of them are converted, I want a a method, `onReduce(Collection<Foo> foos)`, to be called - the argument contains all of the resulting `Foo` instances.

But we can't seem to find an equivalent solution for Reactor 2.x - just single threaded.

How do you perform multi-threaded map/reduce in Reactor 2.x?  For example, how might you do this with an ExecutorService-based Dispatcher?

Comment: Just curious, is there a particular reason you are not using the ForkJoin framework for this?

Comment: @JohnVint Reactor provides a fairly comprehensive API for all sorts of streaming behavior in addition to map/reduce aka fork/join.  We'll be leveraging these other things in our app in various places, so it helps to 'standardize' on a common framework with shared taxonomy so that the overall codebase is more cohesive/maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy now with Reactor 2.0. You could do something like this:

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> data = readData(); // <1>

Streams.from(data)
    .flatMap(m -> Streams.just(m)
                            .dispatchOn(Environment.cachedDispatcher()) // <2>
                            .map(ignored -> Thread.currentThread().getName()))
       .buffer() // <3>
       .consume(s -> System.out.println("s: " + s)); // <4>
```

1. Create a `Stream` based on the input data.
2. Create a new `Stream` for each `Map` and dispatch map operations on the given `Dispatcher`.
3. Buffer all values until complete, which will be sent downstream when collection is emptied.
4. Consume List which is the result of load-balanced transforms from the substream.