# How to catch/detect exceptions in multi-threaded map/reduce using Reactor framework 2.x?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, mapreduce, reactor

I was playing with the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971274/how-to-perform-multi-threaded-map-reduce-using-reactor-framework-2-x/27972689#27972689) and it works smoothly.
However, if an exception is thrown, the caller code does not catch it.

How is an Exception captured in reactor 2.0 streams? 
What I want to do is: if an Exception is thrown, stream processing must stop. I need to throw the Exception up in the caller thread (the one that created the steam in first place).

```
List<Map<String, Object>> data = readData(); 

Streams.from(data)
       .flatMap(m -> Streams.just(m)
                            .dispatchOn(Environment.cachedDispatcher()) 
                            .map(ignored -> {throw new RuntimeException("kaboom!");}))
       .buffer() 
       .consume(s -> System.out.println("s: " + s)); 
// the exception is not thrown and there is not opportunity to deal with it.
```

Answer (score 0):

In Reactor you just need to wrap exceptions and return them as `Flux.error()`

Then you can handle them in `onErrorXXX` methods (eg. `onErrorResume`)

See more:

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling